# How to completely log out of ASP.NET Core server application when using .NET Maui mobile application and Web Authenticator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, maui

I'm working on .NET Maui mobile client with ASP.NET Core backend, and am trying to integrate Google authorization via the [Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios) API built into Maui. I was able to get the login to function by basically following the guide on the Web Authenticator page linked above, but haven't been able to logout from the account I originally logged in with. I've created a logout endpoint for my server, and after I hit this endpoint (where I call `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` ) and compare the value of ClaimsPrinciple, the data from Google is gone (see attached screenshots).

[before logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt6eJ.png)

[after logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2iSd.png)

However, the next time I try to log in I do not need to go through Google authentication, it automatically logs me in again. I've seen similar issues with Web Authenticator (linked [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1712) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1735) and in some other issues linked to these). I'm new at this framework and mobile dev in general and I'm still unclear from these resources what the best way to handle this is - most of these issues are also relating to Xamarins forms rather than Maui, so not sure if theres any more updated solution.

These are the implementations of login and logout and the corresponding requests

```
public class MobileAuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        const string callbackScheme = "myapp";

        [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
        public async Task Get([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

            if (!auth.Succeeded
                || auth?.Principal == null
                || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
            {
                //Not authenticated, challenge
                await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
            }
        
            else
            {
                var claims = auth.Principal.Identities
                    .FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(claim => new
                    {
                        claim.Issuer,
                        claim.OriginalIssuer,
                        claim.Type,
                        claim.Value
                    });

                //Build the result url
                var user = this.User; //CHECK VALUE OF USER
                var url = callbackScheme + "://#";

                //Redirect to final url
                Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);

            }
        }

        [HttpPost("logout")]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
                var url = callbackScheme + "://#";
                var user = this.User; //CHECK VALUE OF USER
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to sign out user {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

```
var url = "http://localhost:5000/mobileauth/logout";
                HttpContent content = null;
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

```
WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
                    new Uri("https://localhost:5001/mobileauth/Google"),
                    new Uri("myapp://"));
```

Edit - I'm primarily confused on how i need to be handling Cookies and access/refresh tokens and the built in claims stuff - like I said, I'm new at this

Comment: I believe you'll still have Google's certificate installed and it's using that.

Comment: I see a suggestion at [What are best practices ...](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1223#issuecomment-879407149): *"For anyone trying to force a new logon - add the optional query string "prompt=login"."*